# How to copy every 16 bytes of data from a string?

Tags: c++, string, copy

I have to copy data into sets of 16 bytes. How do i do it with an easy way?
I've come up with the below algorithm but how do i know if the null terminator has been added? thanks! :)

```
std::string input
//get message to send to client
std::cout << "Enter message to send (type /q to quit) : ";  
getline(std::cin, input);
input += '\n';

const char *data = input.c_str();

len = strlen(data)+1;
int max_len =17;

//split msg into 16 bytes
for(int i = 0; i < len ; i+=max_len)
{
    char tempStr[max_len];
    //get next 16 bytes of msg and store
    for(int j = 0; j < max_len ; j++)
    {           
        tempStr[j] = data[j+i];
    }//end of for loop

     //Do some stuff to tempStr
}
```

Comment: Why don't you do all the string handling with std::string? I mean, make tempStr a std::string, and only use it as a char array when you do "some stuff".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your code, the string terminator is not added. You also skip one character between the copies (since you have `max_len` as `17` while you only copy `16`characters).

I would propose a solution using the standard library instead:

```
std::string::const_iterator pos = input.begin();

while (pos < input.end())
{
    // Create a temporary string containing 17 "null" characters
    char tmp[17] = {'\0' };

    // Make sure we co no copy beyond the end
    std::string::const_iterator end =
        (pos + 16 < input.end() ? pos + 16 : input.end());

    // Do the actual copying
    std::copy(pos, end, tmp);

    // Advance position
    pos += 16;

    // Use the string in 'tmp', it is properly terminated
}
```

Comment: i am confused which would be the better method to use.

Comment: @dupdupdup: I think it depends on what you are doing in `//Do some stuff to tempStr`, would you rather have a C string or a C++ string at that point? Personally I would rather have a C++ string but in this case a C string might be just as easy if you get the null terminators right.

Comment: @jahhaj i would ultimately need it in C string as i will be doing encryption. so if that is the case? i would use Benjamin method?

Comment: @dupdupdup Updated my answer to use a char-array (i.e. a C string) instead.

Answer (score 1):

```
const char* data = input.c_str();
int len = input.size(); // don't add 1
for (int i=0; i<len; i+=16)
{
    char tempStr[17];
    tempStr[16] = 0;
    strncpy(tempStr, data + i, 16);

    // Do some stuff to tempStr
}
```

Depending upon what you actually do with tempStr, there might be a solution that involves no copying at all.

```
for (int i=0; i<len; i+=16)
{
    llvm::StringRef sref(data + i, data + std::min(i+16,len));

    // use sref
}
```

[llvm::StringRef](http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/classllvm_1_1StringRef.html)

Comment: The first set of code gave me a repeat "hello my name ishello my name is" Original string : "hello my name is alice"

Comment: @dupdupdup: I forgot to add `i` to `data`, try it again.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: How so?  strncpy stops copying if it finds a null.